# How do I return a Null Pointer in a function C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, null

I am currently working on a bit of code that will search within a vector of type Person (which I have defined in the code and will show if needed). If it finds the person, it returns their name. This is currently working, but if it does not find the person, it is supposed to return a Null pointer. The problem is, I cannot figure out how to make it return a Null pointer! It just keeps either crashing the program every time.

Code:

```
Person* lookForName(vector<Person*> names, string input)
{
    string searchName = input;
    string foundName;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        Person* p = names[i];
        if (p->getName() == input) {
            p->getName();
            return p; //This works fine. No problems here
            break; 
        } else {
            //Not working Person* p = NULL; <---Here is where the error is happening
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just return '0' (zero). That is the representation of a null pointer in C++.

Comment: `nullptr` would be better, but seriously, use `std::find_if` and preferably a `std::vector<Person>` without the pointer.

Comment: Oh and also you weren't initialising P so in almost any case it would have a value != 0. Remember that C++ doesn't initialise it's variables automatically.

Comment: @MrUniverse, I see it being initialized.

Comment: You have a serious logic error here - this loop will never execute more than once, since each branch of the `if` returns.

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas! I am attempting to use std::find_if but am having some compile errors. I'll keep at it though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm:

```
Person * lookForName(vector<Person*> &names, const std::string& input)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(names.begin(), names.end(),
              [&input](Person* p){ return p->getName() == input; });


    return it != names.end() ? *it : nullptr; // if iterator reaches names.end(), it's not found
}
```

For C++03 version:

```
struct isSameName
{
    explicit isSameName(const std::string& name)
    : name_(name)
    {
    }

    bool operator()(Person* p)
    {
       return p->getName() == name_;
    }
    std::string name_;
};

Person * lookForName(vector<Person*> &names, const std::string& input)
{
    vector<Person*>::iterator it = std::find_if(names.begin(), names.end(),
                           isSameName(input));


    return it != names.end() ? *it : NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! One quick Q though, I pasted this code in place of my existing code and it is coming up with "error: 'it' does not name a type." Should I delete part of the code? or do I need to declare it somewhere else?

Comment: @Silmarilos: It seems that you are compiling with a C++03 compiler, or otherwise in C++03 mode. The solution above depends on some C++11 features, namely `auto` type inference, lambdas and `nullptr`. You can unroll the loop manually or define a functor out-of-line (outside of the function) to use `std::find_if`

Answer (score 2):

If the name you are searching for is not at the first element, then you are not searching in the rest of the elements.

You need to do something like -

```
for (int i = 0; i<names.size(); i++){
    Person* p = names[i];
    if (p->getName() == input) {
        return p;

        // Placing break statement here has no meaning as it won't be executed.
    } 
}

// Flow reaches here if the name is not found in the vector. So, just return NULL
return NULL;
```

As Chris suggested, try using `std::find_if` algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just have to return Null, nullptr, or 0.

[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/367729/How-to-return-a-null-pointer-in-cplusplus)

Answer (score 0):

Just use following code:

```
return NULL;
```